# elm-make: elm-package.json: openBinaryFile: does not exist

Tags: elm, elm-make, elm-0.18

- I do a fresh installation: `npm i elm@0.18 -g`
- I try to build using: `elm-make ./src/scripts/MainModule.elm`
- I get:

> elm-make: elm-package.json: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)

But the `elm-package.json` file is right there in the directory where `elm-make` is called from.

Thoughts?

Note: I'm using [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm), in case it matters.

Comment: Note, also [cross-posted on the Elm discourse](https://discourse.elm-lang.org/t/elm-make-elm-package-json-openbinaryfile-does-not-exist/3260/2)

Comment: [Cross-posting is discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266053/is-it-ok-to-cross-post-a-question-between-non-stack-exchange-and-stack-exchange), especially when it's done immediately and without any reference to each other, because it wastes the time of those who try to help, and potentially also those looking for answers later if you don't follow up properly.

Comment: I just added reference from discourse. I was about to add it here as well. Should I add it, or should I leave this as is with your comment?

Comment: Just as a comment is probably fine. Properly cross-referencing answers is more important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that package authors were updating packages to support elm .19 by changing `elm-package.json` to `elm.json` but not bumping up major versions of their packages.

Answer (score 2):

I am able to reproduce the error by deleting `elm-package.json`, but leaving the `elm-stuff/` directory. You should be able to fix this by deleting your `elm-stuff/` directory and letting `elm-make` rebuild the project for you.

For reference, issue here: https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-make/issues/171

Answer (score 0):

@HParker is right, the only way to reproduce it is following these steps:

1. Run `elm-make` and let it install all the dependencies
2. Remove `elm-package.json` file
3. Run `elm-make` again

If it's not your case you can debug what's going using `strace`, e. g.

`strace -yfv elm-make 2>&1 | grep elm-package.json`

Example output:

```
[pid 32319] openat(AT_FDCWD, "elm-package.json", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 32319] write(2<pipe:[427229]>, "elm-package.json: openBinaryFile"..., 76elm-package.json: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)) = 76
```

If it tries to open `elm-package.json` in current working directory you will see `AT_FDCWD` variable, if not you should see the full path.